# Overlap background until an element

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-flex-layout

I try to overlap my background with the start of my cards (like on the stackblitz but cleanly). My goal is that it stops precisely under the title of the card. I tried to do it with a percentage of the page size but it is not clean and does not work very well (size which changes with responsive design, zoom, ...).
I also tried to calculate the height but it gets complicated very quickly (the title is in the child of the child of the child)
I'm looking for another solution, do you have any ideas?

What I'm looking for :
[image]

**Stackblitz** : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sjgvvx

What

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make two sections. Say `header` and `section`. The header gets the background and `padding-bottom`. The cards live in the section container and get **NEGATIVE** `margin-top` equal to the card padding + text height.

This way you can add as much as you want to the header and it will always push the other stuff down.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  background-color: blue;
}
header {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 10px 50px 10px;
}

.tiles {
  /* this is the important part. Make sure top margin = top padding + height of text */
  margin: -25px 10px 0 10px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.tile {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h2>Some Header Content</h2>
</header>
<section>
<div class="tiles">
  <div class="tile">Tile Content</div>
  <div class="tile">Tile Content</div>
  <div class="tile">Tile Content</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: I was thinking along those lines but I think OP wants the first (red) block to stop right below the green (card) block's title. Might be a bit complex… unless using subgrid? Your solution seems like a good compromise, though.

Comment: Negative margin is the simple way to pull content over something lower in the stacking order (by default later items in the DOM are above earlier items)

Comment: Fully aware and fully agreeing with you, just pointing out that it might not follow OP's requirements. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I had to adapt it slightly but it is the one that works best for the moment

Answer (score 0):

Not optimal but doable, One hackey way is to apply the background using pseuo-Element from the header so ***that it stops precisely under the title of the card***.

```css
.container {
    padding: 50px 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container>div {
    background: lime;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container>div>.card {
    flex: 1 0 40%;
    margin: 15px;
    background: pink;
}



/* Solution */
.card>h1 {
    position: relative;
}

.card>h1:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    
    /* huge numbers to ensure that it fits if screen is too large */
    width: 10000px;
    height: 10000px;
    left: -1000px;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>title-page</h1>
    <span>Subtitle</span>
    <div>
        <div class="card">
            <h1>Title card</h1>
            <p>babfkds sbdf ksdbfl bdslkfb kdsbflk</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <p>example2 works!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <p>example3 works!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution is really great with pure html/css but with angular i need to use the ::nd-deep selector and the :before take all the component (the card) even if i specify the h1 inside the card :/

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angular. So If you can't use the pseudo-Element just add another element within the h1 and apply the same styles to it, Also if you plan on having a background instead of the red one chances are this solution isn't for you.